# iPhone Retina Graphics

Tags: iphone

I have a question RE Retina display graphics (and potentially iPad 2 graphics if the rumours of double resolution displays are to be believed).

Is there any advantage to having two graphics:
Graphic.png 480x320
and 
Graphic@2.png 960x640

and letting the iPhone use the @2 version for retina displays rather than just having Graphic.png at the higher res and letting iPhones with normal displays squash it?

Comment: @the "exact duplicate" usually means the questions are exactly the same (i.e., repost).  [We're tending to let similar questions stand, now.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)  Feel free to vote to close as dupe once you get your rep above 3k, however.

Comment: A bit old now with 3 generations of iPads out. BUT one funny thing is that if you leave out the 1x graphics and run your app in 2x on the first two generations of iPads (with at least iOS 4.0) it will look better than if you also include 1x graphics. Because with 1x graphics in there as well, the old iPads will think "Hey these are for me" and use them, and obviously in 2x resolution that will look bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If you didn't use two separate graphics (normal and "@2x"), any device without the retina display would have to store its graphics using **four times as much memory**. It's a simple matter of storing an insignificant amount of compressed images (PNGs) so you don't have to kill legacy devices' memory.

Not only that, but performance will drop from having to handle such large images on devices that are generally slower.

Finally, the result of scaling huge images is usually really ugly, because UIKit uses the nearest-neighbor algorithm when scaling.

Comment: But surely if I do it as two separate graphics I have a small image of 1k, a large image of 4k therefore total size in the package is 5k instead of 4k if we went for one or am I missing something?

Comment: That's true, and there's your technical trade-off. Still, I believe Apple suggests prioritizing proper human-computer interface design over minimizing package size.

Comment: An iPhone 3G has 128MB of ram and 16-32GB of disk space. Using more disk space to use less ram seems like a very clear win to me.

Comment: @faroligo : it's not about the package size, it's about the size it will take in memory

Comment: OK yes, that all makes perfect sense.  So technically, if you are using the exact same image and there are no scaling issues then doubling the res of the original image instead of using an @2 is the same thing EXCEPT for the memory that image will take up when loaded in to RAM.  For that reason it is recommended to have a slightly larger package instead.  Thanks all for the clarification.